# Specific WPF binding lost when unloading / reloading view

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I have a very peculiar and annoying issue that I can't get my head around. It's a bit difficult to explain so bear with me.

**The background** is that I have an app with 2 views and I can switch back-and-forth between the 2. This is implemented using MVVM, so that I have a main window with a ContentControl. The Content of the ContentControl is bound to CurrentViewModel property in the MainViewModel.
Switching is by using commandbindings that set the CurrentViewModel to one or the other ViewModel of my 2 different views.
The 2 ViewModels are linked to the Views by DataTemplate definitions in App.xaml. I believe this is a fairly common setup.
(Note, in the current implementation I use MvvmLight and the ViewModels are managed using its SimpleIOC)

**The problem** is now if I have a ToggleButton in one view with some custom content (rectangle and circle) drawn for toggled / untoggled state. This is achieved using style triggers (or DataTriggers). There's still no issue until here, but if I bind the Fill property to the Foreground color of the ToggleButton (see code sample below) something strange happens:

1. Toggle button, switch to second view, switch back, untoggle button - the drawing is not rendered (reason is that binding for Fill doesn't work), but there's no problem with the other content for toggled state
2. Once the untoggled drawing is lost, in this untoggled state switch to second view then switch back - the drawing on untoggled state is miraculously back and both state (toggled / untoggled) are rendered correctly

**EDIT:**
The error I get when switching back:
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=TB1'. BindingExpression:Path=Foreground; DataItem=null; target element is 'Ellipse' (Name=''); target property is 'Fill' (type 'Brush')

Anybody has a clue where the issue comes from and how to fix this?
I was thinking to simplify the test app, exclude all MvvmLight / IOC, but I doubt that issue is related to this.

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="TB1"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" Width="30"
Command="{Binding Toggle1}"
IsChecked="{Binding IsToggled1}">
<ToggleButton.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Setter Property="Content" >
            <Setter.Value>
                <Rectangle Width="17" Height="17" Fill="{Binding ElementName=TB1, Path=Foreground}" />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsToggled1}" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Content">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <Ellipse Width="17" Height="17" Fill="{Binding ElementName=TB1, Path=Foreground}" />
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ToggleButton.Style>
```

Comment: Would you please try a RelativeSource binding to the parent ToggleButton? That should work.

Comment: @oddparity Oh, but that's how I wrote it first time, just tried to fiddle around with xaml. However, I always get same issue, so it must be something much "deeper" than that

Comment: The interesting thing is when I snoop the ToggleButton, the Rectangle is there. It even gets visible as soon as I click on it in Snoop's tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have trouble with **XAML namescopes**. It's like variable scope, just for XAML names. XAML namescope is created on a root element of XAML page, *but Styles and Templates have their own namescopes* because they are reusable. Let's say that Rectangle or Ellipse from your Style had a Name, and you had 5 ToggleButtons in your view using that Style. If Styles didn't have their own namescopes you would have 5 elements with the same name in same namescope.
When XAML is parsed, one of the Content property values is applied (depending on IsChecked state of ToggleButton). It enters the namescope of TogglButton and that ElementName is resolved, but the other stays outside of namescope and can't be resolved.

So what can you do? You can use `x:Reference` markup extension. So, instead of `ElementName=TB1` you could use `Source={x:Reference TB1}`. But then XAML parser will throw a cyclical dependency exception, because your reference would point to an element containing the reference (your Style is defined within your ToggleButton). To remedy this, define your style as a resource:

```
<Window.Resources>
  <Style x:key="TBStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
     <Setter Property="Content">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Rectangle Width="17" Height="17"
                     Fill="{Binding Foreground, Source={x:Reference TB1}}"/>
        </Setter.Value>
     </Setter>
     <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsToggled1}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Content">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <Ellipse Width="17" Height="17"
                 Fill="{Binding Foreground, Source={x:Reference TB1}}}" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
</Window.Resources>
....
<ToggleButton x:Name="TB1"
              Margin="5"
              Width="30"
              Height="30"
              IsChecked="{Binding IsToggled1}"
              Style="{StaticResource TBStyle}"/>
```

If you applied this style to 5 ToggleButtons, they would all pick Foreground color from that one button named "TB1", but that is completely different issue.

Comment: That works, thanks! I have to brush up on my `x:Reference` as it is still a bit blurry why one ElementName (or FindAncestor) can be resolved and the other can't. But since this indeed solves the issue I marked your reply as answer.

Comment: I tried to explain that in the answer (check out the last 2 sentences in first paragraph). Rectangle and Ellipse elements are created within the Style, they are not part of the element tree until one of them becomes the actual Content of the ToggleButton (until then, it doesn't have an ancestor of ToggleButton type yet, and it's namescope doesn't have an element named TB1).

Comment: I know, it's more on my side to wrap my head around it, thanks.